# Running git pull in Shiny app

Tags: r, git, shiny, bitbucket

I've got a shiny app on a Ubuntu 16.04 EC2 instance and I want to be able to update it via a webhook when there's a push to the repo. So I set up another shiny app to receive the webook. I know that doing this through a shiny app is *very* much less than optimal, but I just want to get something going now and then I'll come back later with a better solution.

So I set the webhook to request a certain url, but currently that doesn't matter. The problem I'm having when I load the page is that the app can't run `git pull` via `system2` (or `system` for that matter). The user shiny can successfully run `git pull`, and it can also successfully run `git pull` via a `system2` or `system` command in the R interpreter.

Here's what the app looks like:

```
library(shiny)

setwd("/home/shiny/myrepo")
result <- system2("git", "pull", stdout = TRUE, stderr = TRUE)

ui <- bootstrapPage(
        textOutput("result")
)


# Define the server code
server <- function(input, output) {
        output$result <- renderText(result)
}

# Return a Shiny app object
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

When I load the page

```
Permission denied (publickey).
 fatal: Could not read from remote repository. Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.
```

Is there something I'm not accounting for with how Shiny server runs? My ssh key is stored in `keychain` with an `ssh-agent`, so that shouldn't be a problem. The permissions are correct, I believe, on the app.R file and the repo (shiny is the owner and group on both, and, again, can perform the `git pull` on the repo from the shell and from the R interpreter).

I'm guessing it's something to do with Shiny server and its ability to access the /home/shiny/.ssh folder?

Answer (score 0):

You can check the user explicitly by printing the info in the window.

If you are running a [default configuration](http://docs.rstudio.com/shiny-server/#default-configuration) of Shiny Server you'll be serving up any apps under the directory `/srv/shiny-server`.

Try putting this in `/srv/shiny-server/test-repo-pull/app.R`, then accessing from `<your-host>:3838/test-repo-pull`:

```
library("shiny")

ui <- bootstrapPage(
  actionButton("pull", "Pull Master Branch"),
  verbatimTextOutput("result"),
  tableOutput("user")
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  result <- eventReactive(input$pull, {
    system2("git", "pull origin master", stdout = TRUE, stderr = TRUE)
  })

  output$user <- renderTable({
    info <- Sys.info()
    data.frame(variable = names(info), values = unname(info))
  })

  output$result <- renderPrint({
    result()
  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Note that you should not be executing `setwd` in apps that are being run by Shiny Server but rather handle any temporary handling of your files explicitly (if needed).

More likely this is a permissions issue relating to not having your [public SSH key configured with BitBucket](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bbkb/permission-denied-publickey-302811860.html), have you configured home directories to run as their owner user in `/etc/shiny-server/shiny-server.conf` (instead of user `shiny`)?

Comment: First of all, thanks for taking your tie for a detailed response.

I've verified that the user is shiny. The shiny user has the key in the .ssh/ folder, and it is the correct key because it is able to push when I'm logged in as that user on the server. I can even run R and push from R either via system2 or the git2r package as the **shiny** user. So something changes once it's shiny server executing.

Comment: what happens if you do a `git init` in the directory the app is running in and set `git remote add origin master <repo-url>` instead of trying to run with the `-C` flag? While you're at it can you please update your question with your OS?

Comment: For example:
`> system2("git", "-C /home/shiny/myrepo pull origin master", stdout=T, stderr=T)
[1] "From bitbucket.org:me/myrepo"   
[2] " * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD"
[3] "Already up-to-date."`

But running essentially the same thing on the server gives me:
`[1] "Permission denied (publickey).\r"                   
[2] "fatal: Could not read from remote repository."      
`

Comment: Interestingly enough, `git -C /home/shiny/myrepo status` does work. (I've got the shiny server config set up to point to this, sorry I didn't clarify earlier.)